# Qt not locating slots in simple example program

Tags: qt

This is a simple example that fails to run.  The run-time errors are:

```
QObject::connect: No such slot Bridge::setText(const QString& text)
QObject::connect: No such slot QLabel::setText(const QString& text)
```

I have two files, main.cpp and Bridge.h.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QtWidgets>
#include "Bridge.h"

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  QApplication app (argc, argv);

  QWidget widget;
  QLineEdit * lineEdit = new QLineEdit;
  QLabel * label = new QLabel;

  QVBoxLayout * layout = new QVBoxLayout;
  layout->addWidget(lineEdit);
  layout->addWidget(label);
  widget.setLayout(layout);

  Bridge * bridge = new Bridge ("", &app);

  QObject::connect(
    lineEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged(const QString &)),
    bridge, SLOT(setText(const QString & text))
  );

  QObject::connect(
    bridge, SIGNAL(textChanged(const QString &)),
    label, SLOT(setText(const QString & text))
  );

  widget.show();

  return app.exec();
}
```

**Bridge.h**

```
#include <QString>
#include <QObject>

class Bridge : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  Bridge(const QString & text, QObject * parent = 0) : QObject(parent), text(text) {}

  const QString & getText() const;
  int getLengthOfText() const;

public slots:
  void setText(const QString & text) {
    if (this->text == text) {
      return;
    }
    this->text = text;
    emit textChanged(text);
  }

signals:
  void textChanged(const QString &);

private:
  QString text;
};
```

**.pro file**

```
######################################################################
# Automatically generated by qmake (3.0) Sat May 17 20:28:07 2014
######################################################################

TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = qtbox
INCLUDEPATH += .
INCLUDEPATH += headers

QT += widgets

# Input
HEADERS += headers/Bridge.h

SOURCES += sources/main.cpp

######################################################################
# Build to custom directories
######################################################################

release: DESTDIR = build/release
debug:   DESTDIR = build/debug

OBJECTS_DIR = $$DESTDIR/.obj
MOC_DIR = $$DESTDIR/.moc
RCC_DIR = $$DESTDIR/.qrc
UI_DIR = $$DESTDIR/.ui
```

Am I missing something obvious here?  Some random things I can come up with:

1. Do I need to define setText in a .cpp file?  If so, why would I have to do this?
2. Is whitespace a problem?  ie `QString&` vs `QString &`
3. Am I missing something in my qmake file?

Comment: Why don't you tag this with C++?

Comment: @sashoalm The question has to do with the workings of the Qt Macro.  Doesn't seem applicable to all of C++ questions.

Comment: Hint, when using the "old-style" connect with `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` macros, *let Qt Creator complete them for you*. If it doesn't want to, you'll know there's some syntax problem in your code. And when it does autocompletion, you avoid mistakes like this, and actual typos etc too.

Comment: Why is this voted to be closed?  Quote: "What questions can I ask here?"  Answer: "A specific programming problem"  It also seems to follow all 7 guidelines further in the FAQ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No, you do not. But it is common to do so, especially if you need to change your implementation; you will not have to recompile all files that include that header file.
2. No, both are valid.
3. No, also, the qmake file seems valid.

Change your connect calls not to have a variable, but only the type:

```
connect(bridge, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)), label, SLOT(setText(QString)));
```

Edit: Also, `#include <QLabel>` to eventually run qmake manually once.